# Добавление exif и сохранение файла полностью перезаписывают исходный файл?

Tags: c#, .net, gdi, gdi+

С помощью стандартной библиотеки для работы с картинками в .net можно добавлять собственные метаданные к картинкам, иначе говоря exif. Собственно вопрос, а при добавлении метаданных и сохранении файла исходный файл полностью перезаписывается или происходит быстрая дозапись метаданных? Если первое, то можно ли как нибудь лишь дозаписывать информацию, неперезаписывая файл целиком? 
Дело в том, что полная перезапись файла отрицательно скажется на производительности, если потребуется прописать метаданные для большого кол ва файлов.

Comment: И какую из библиотек вы имеете в виду? Winforms или WPF? Обе стандартные.

Comment: @VladD Winforms. Разве в WPF есть что-то для работы с картинками? Сколько не искал примеры, все используют примитив Image из WinForms.

Comment: Целая гора: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging(v=vs.110).aspx. Одних только [потомков `BitmapSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0) 10 штук.

Comment: @VladD, они полностью покрываю функционал WinForms (Drawing) или все таки время от времени что-то нужно брать от туда? А производительность выше? Если не ошибаюсь, то там видеокарта используется, а не процессор?

Comment: На это мне сложно ответить, я никогда не занимался сравнением. Мне всегда хватало функциональности WPF для работы с картинками.

Answer (score 2):

Я нигде в .NET не встречал дозаписи в файлы (кроме текстовых).

Причина простая. Пусть вы читаете в память из файла какой-то объект, модифицируете его, и записываете назад. Для того, чтобы дозапись имела смысл, ваша запись должна происходить в тот же файл, должна быть какая-то гарантия, что данные в файле не поменялись за время обработки, и ваши изменения в объекте должны располагаться в файле строго после уже вбитой в файл информации, или не менять длину частей файла.

Все эти условия достаточно сложны, и приводят к оптимизации в достаточно маленьком проценте сценариев использования. Поэтому ответ — нет, файл будет полностью переписан заново.

---

Если вам нужна такая оптимизация — лучше всего наверное написать собственный велосипед, который будет заниматься *только* правкой метаданных. Вам придётся при этом освоить нужные форматы файлов, да.